# Exterior derivative leibniz rule geometric

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I‘ve watched the video of Keenan Crane on the exterior derivative https://youtu.be/jeiDXhCiF44 where he explains that the product rule of differential forms just describes how little volumes change. So I‘ve drawn a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cskF.png) which is almost the classic visualization of the product rule for functions.
Here are $v$ and $w$ 1-forms which are visualized as vectors.
The product rule now states that:
$$\mathrm{d}(v\wedge w)= \mathrm{d}v\wedge w - v\wedge \mathrm{d} w $$
But than the geometric interpretation brakes down because when we view the wedge product of $v$ and $w$ as a (equivalence-class of) orientated parallelogram the second term should have a plus sign because of the same orientation.
So where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crane's heuristic is a good one (and a common one), but the precise analogy breaks down, indeed, here. This is not the correct product rule when you work with actual vectors (i.e., vector functions). There is no sign. The point is that differentiating a vector gives a mixed sort of object — a vector-valued $1$-form, and $d(u\wedge v)$ will be a $2$-vector valued $1$-form. For example, if
$$u = f(t)e_1 \quad\text{and}\quad v = g(t)e_1 + h(t)e_2,$$
then $u\wedge v = f(t)h(t) e_1\wedge e_2$ and
$$d(u\wedge v) = (f'(t)h(t)+f(t)h'(t))dt\, e_1\wedge e_2 = du\wedge v \color{red}{+} u\wedge dv,$$
because $dt$ commutes with vectors. (Most mathematicians will write $dt\otimes e_1$ and $dt\otimes e_1\wedge e_2$ when unlike objects — here, $1$-forms and vectors or $2$-vectors — are combined multiplicatively.)

On the other hand, when you work with differential forms, the basis $1$-forms interfere with one another and the sign comes in from interchanging them. For example, if
$$\omega = f(x,y,z)dx \quad\text{and}\quad \eta = g(x,y,z)dy,$$
then $\omega\wedge\eta = f(x,y,z)g(x,y,z)dx\wedge dy$ and
$$d(\omega\wedge\eta) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}g+f\frac{\partial g}{\partial z})dz\wedge dx\wedge dy;$$
note the other partials do not appear because $dx\wedge dx=0$ and $dy\wedge dy=0$.
Continuing the computation,
$$
(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}g+f\frac{\partial g}{\partial z})dz\wedge dx\wedge dy = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz\wedge dx)\wedge (g dy) \color{red}{-}
(f\,dx)\wedge(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}dz\wedge dy),$$
because $dx\wedge dz\wedge dy = -dz\wedge dx\wedge dy$. Thus, with actual $1$-forms, we have
$$d(\omega\wedge\eta) = d\omega\wedge\eta \color{red}-\omega\wedge d\eta,$$
as promised.

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance but I thought again what the geometric reason for the alternating minus sign is. And the only reason I could find was in the “infinitesimal Stokes theorem” definition of the exterior derivative where the alternating sign came from the definition of the boundary of a cell. So would it be possible to define a derivative which would agree with the geometric intuition and for which Stokes theorem would be also valid for a different definition of the boundary? But because it would be so artificial and we would loose properties like $\partial^2=0$ nobody does.

Comment: @Silas You can relate it to $\partial$, of course, but my point here is that it is forced on you by the exterior algebra (the fact that $\wedge$ is skew-commutative).

Comment: The algebraic reason is clear. It's just unclear to me how all this fits together with the geometric intuition that we get e.g. from the Divergence theorem. Because if we have a two form $\omega$ we get for d$\omega(v_1,v_2,v_3)=\lim_{h->0}\frac{1}{h^3}\int_{\partial P(h)}\omega$ a sum over every change in the directions spanned from the vectors in the infinitesimal parallelepiped $P(h)$ but the direction from $v_2$ gets a minus sign. So does the definition of the boundary compensate the alternating adding of the individual contributions such that we get the same result for the Div. theorem?

Comment: Yes, it's corresponding exactly to the orientations on the boundary of, say, a cube. Work it out for Green's Theorem and a rectangle. This is the physicists' "proof" in the first place: Find the work done around a rectangle with sides $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$.